# Establish empty tuple in tuple of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I do a test that returns true if no tuple within a tuple of tuples is empty?

For example, return `True` in this case:

```
(('t2',), ('t3',), ('t4',), ('t5','t6'))
```

return `False` in this case:

```
(('t2',), (), ('t3',), ('t4',))
```

Please give your answer so that it is valid for Python3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in `all` function as empty tuple is falsey in Python:

```
Help on built-in function all in module builtins:

all(...)
    all(iterable) -> bool

    Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
    If the iterable is empty, return True.



>>> all((('t2',), ('t3',), ('t4',), ('t5', 't6')))
True
>>> all((('t2',), (), ('t3',), ('t4',)))
False
```

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of "no tuple within a tuple of tuples is empty" is "some tuple... is empty"; equivalently, "an empty tuple can be found within the tuple of tuples".

This naturally leads to an equally simple (and, I think, marginally more readable) but quite different solution:

```
>>> () not in (('t2',), ('t3',), ('t4',), ('t5', 't6'))
True
>>> () not in (('t2',), (), ('t3',), ('t4',))
False
```